# Is any element in the closed linear span is series of scalar multiplied elements of the span?

Tags: functional-analysis

I've found two answers which seem to contradict eachother;

This first one makes me 100% sure that its not the case, 
[Closure of the span in a Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169257/closure-of-the-span-in-a-banach-space)

But I cant figue out why the second one almost also do..when it shouldt

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104672/infinite-linear-span-vs-closed-linear-span

Comment: The second one shows: the closed linear span of a linear subspace of a normed space is the set of sums of infinite series.  The first one shows it fails when the subset is not already a linear space.

Comment: @GEdgar do you mind clarify "the set of sums of infinite series" ?

Comment: If you do not understand one of those links, why not ask there?

Comment: @GEdgar I think I understand it, but "set of sums of infinite series" made me think twice. According to me the second is using "series of linear combainations from A" when constructing the sequence. Sums of series would be a finite number of infinte sums added together which I dont think he is doing.

Comment: By "sum of an infinite series" I mean "limit of the partial sums of the series"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GEdgar points out ;

The second one shows: the closed linear span of a linear subspace of a normed space is the set of sums of infinite series. The first one shows it fails when the subset is not already a linear space. By "sum of an infinite series" he means "limit of the partial sums of the series"